# XSLT: XML to HTML Transform - No Line Breaks

Tags: .net, xml, xslt

I am transforming an XML document via XSLT into an HTML document. In my XSLT I have indent set to "yes." The resulting HTML is all on a single line except for where I have specifically inserted new-line characters. Why isn't the resulting HTML (XML) being formatted with new-lines and indents?

I'm using Oxygen to do the transform and the .Net 2.0 engine.

Comment: Could you, please, provide a small (but complete) example? XML document, XSLT code and the result that you are getting? Otherwise we would not be able to repro the problem and you won't get any sensible advice beyond guesses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<xsl:output method="html"/>
```

as a top-level element

EDIT: see comments
The default for @indent on method="html" is "yes" and for xml is "no"

Comment: Sitching to HTML output method worked. I had this set before but I didn't like the way it was treating some elements (can't remember specifically which ones). I'm still unclear why XML output method does not generate line breaks.

Comment: @Josh M.: This has nothing to do with your problem. `xml` serialization method also allow identation.

Comment: Besides this was usefull for the OP, you might want to consider others reading this question. `xsl:output/@indent` has `no` as default value for `xml` method, and `yes` as default value for `html` method.

Comment: I am unsurprised that you had trouble - controlling XSLT output is an experimental science!

Comment: +1000 if I could... You saved me a lot of headaches, thanks :)